# Python: Simple WebServer not accessible from other interface than loopback?

Tags: python, networking, webserver

I have a simple question (well, at lease I hope it's simple). I have downloaded a python script which is actually a simple webserver. After I type into the browser 127.0.0.1:8080, the browser displays a message because the webserver knows how to handle GET requests. I have a static IP, however, if I try my.static.ip.address:8080 it doesnt work. It cant access the server. Is it that ubuntu does not let it, or?

Anyways, here's the code:

```
import time
import BaseHTTPServer


HOST_NAME = 'example.net' # !!!REMEMBER TO CHANGE THIS!!!
PORT_NUMBER = 8080 # Maybe set this to 9000.


class MyHandler(BaseHTTPServer.BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
    def do_HEAD(s):
        s.send_response(200)
        s.send_header("Content-type", "text/html")
        s.end_headers()
    def do_GET(s):
        """Respond to a GET request."""
        s.send_response(200)
        s.send_header("Content-type", "text/html")
        s.end_headers()
        s.wfile.write("<html><head><title>Title goes here.</title></head>")
        s.wfile.write("<body><p>This is a test.</p>")
        # If someone went to "http://something.somewhere.net/foo/bar/",
        # then s.path equals "/foo/bar/".
        s.wfile.write("<p>You accessed path: %s</p>" % s.path)
        s.wfile.write("</body></html>")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    server_class = BaseHTTPServer.HTTPServer
    httpd = server_class((HOST_NAME, PORT_NUMBER), MyHandler)
    print time.asctime(), "Server Starts - %s:%s" % (HOST_NAME, PORT_NUMBER)
    try:
        httpd.serve_forever()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        pass
    httpd.server_close()
    print time.asctime(), "Server Stops - %s:%s" % (HOST_NAME, PORT_NUMBER)
```

Comment: [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14027023/4014959) may be helpful

Comment: Also see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Port_forwarding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The binding interface, that you named `HOST_NAME` should be 'any address' e.g.

```
HOST_NAME = '0.0.0.0'
```

Comment: I'll give it a try, didn't think about this, thanks :) If it works you get an upvote

Answer (score 0):

BaseHTTPServer inherits from SocketServer.TCPServer.

Let's look at its constructor:

```
class TCPServer(BaseServer):

    def __init__(self, server_address, RequestHandlerClass, bind_and_activate=True):
        BaseServer.__init__(self, server_address, RequestHandlerClass)
        self.socket = socket.socket(self.address_family, self.socket_type)
        if bind_and_activate:
            try:
                self.server_bind()
                self.server_activate()
            except:
                self.server_close()
                raise
```

Ok, so now let's look at this server_bind() method:

```
def server_bind(self):
    if self.allow_reuse_address:
        self.socket.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
    self.socket.bind(self.server_address)
    self.server_address = self.socket.getsockname()
```

So, you have bound the underlying socket of your HTTP server to the host 'example.net' on port 8080. That means that your server is not bound on IP address my.static.ip.address.

Try to put instead:
HOST_NAME = 'my.static.ip.address'

Comment: well, my.static.ip.address was just meant to be something like 127.0.0.1 but my real IP, not the lopback. I just didnt want to post my real IP here. Whatever I put there as host name is just a string. I want to be able to connect to this server using my own real IP address.

Comment: try "telnet 127.0.0.1 8080" (should connect) and then "telnet st.at.ic.ip 8080" (replacing with your IP) and compare results.

Comment: and ubuntu may have a preconfigured firewall to block traffic from internet. in any case it's probably not a python problem.